# CloudHarmonyの結果の見方

Tags: aws, network

## やりたいこと

AWS S3の速度をリージョンごとに比較したいです。

http://cloudharmony.com/speedtest-for-aws:s3-ap-northeast-1-aws:s3-ap-northeast-2-and-aws:s3-ap-southeast-1

## 質問

Downlinkが2種類ありますが、どう違うのでしょうか？

- "1-128KB"は通常のHTTPリクエスト、"256KB-10MB"はファイルのダウンロードを想定しているのでしょうか？
- "1-128KB"より"256KB-10MB"の方が同じ通信量に対してのオーバヘッドが少ないので、"256KB-10MB"の方が速度は大きい、という認識で合っていますか？
- ここで表示されている"thread"は何を指しますか？
- "1-128KB"と"256KB-10MB"で、分母のthreadsが異なるのは、どう捉えればよいですか？
- ap-northeast1のDownlink速度は、"1-128KB"で4.81Mbps, "256KB-10MB"で4.84Mbpsでした。これはオーバヘッドがなくなったとしても、実測の最大速度は約4.8Mbpsまでしか出ない、という認識で合っていますか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブラウザにChromeをお使いであれば、Developer ConsoleのNetworkから何をdownloadしているのかを見れますね。これを見る限りで各質問にお答えしますね。

> "1-128KB"は通常のHTTPリクエスト、"256KB-10MB"はファイルのダウンロードを想定しているのでしょうか？

`1-128KB`, `256KB-10MB` いずれもjpg画像のdownloadを行っておりました。

> "1-128KB"より"256KB-10MB"の方が同じ通信量に対してのオーバヘッドが少ないので、"256KB-10MB"の方が速度は大きい、という認識で合っていますか？

そうなるかと思われます。

> ここで表示されている"thread"は何を指しますか？

file downloadの並列実行数ですね。

> "1-128KB"と"256KB-10MB"で、分母のthreadsが異なるのは、どう捉えればよいですか？

`1-128KB`はdownloadするjpg画像が1KBから128KBの間にあるよ、ということを意味しております。例えば、5.3KB, 101.KBのjpg画像をdownloadするということになります。

`1-128KB / 4 threads`より`256KB-10MB / 2 threads`の方が同時並列実行数が少ないのは、同時間にdownloadできるサイズを考慮してのことではないかと思います。

> ap-northeast1のDownlink速度は、"1-128KB"で4.81Mbps, "256KB-10MB"で4.84Mbpsでした。これはオーバヘッドがなくなったとしても、実測の最大速度は約4.8Mbpsまでしか出ない、という認識で合っていますか？

結果から察するにそういう結論になるかと思われます。
ただ、2019/01/06 22:27:40時点で私の環境下では、ap-northeast1 `1-128KB 4 threads`: 3.68 Mb/s, `256KB-10MB / 2 threads`: 30.56 Mb/s でした。